# flutter DataTable: columns and rows property not defined problem

Tags: flutter, material-ui, flutter-layout

I've started developing in Flutter with tables, but I met some problems with tables.

I use DataTable to represent data in a table. There is a  problem that i face (The named parameter 'columns' isn't defined.
Try correcting the name to an existing named parameter's name, or defining a named parameter with the name 'columns'). it dos not recognize column's and rows property in DataTable widget. here is my code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class DataTable extends StatelessWidget {
  @override


enter code heWidget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
     body: SingleChildScrollView(
      child: DataTable(
    columns:  <DataColumn>[
        DataColumn(
          label: Text(
            'Name',
            style: TextStyle(fontStyle: FontStyle.italic),
          ),
        ),
        DataColumn(
          label: Text(
            'Age',
            style: TextStyle(fontStyle: FontStyle.italic),
          ),
        ),
        DataColumn(
          label: Text(
            'Designation',
            style: TextStyle(fontStyle: FontStyle.italic),
          ),
        ),
    ],
    rows: const <DataRow>[
        DataRow(
          cells: <DataCell>[
            DataCell(Text('Mohit')),
            DataCell(Text('23')),
            DataCell(Text('Associate Software Developer')),
          ],
        ),
        DataRow(
          cells: <DataCell>[
            DataCell(Text('Akshay')),
            DataCell(Text('25')),
            DataCell(Text('Software Developer')),
          ],
        ),
        DataRow(
          cells: <DataCell>[
            DataCell(Text('Deepak')),
            DataCell(Text('29')),
            DataCell(Text('Team Lead ')),
          ],
        ),
    ],
  ),
     ),
);
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your class is named `DataTable` which clashes with the `DataTable` widget found in the `material.dart`.

Since dart first checks the current scope while resolving conflicts, the `DataTable` that you are using inside your `build` is referencing your own `DataTable` Stateless widget.

Rename it to `MyDataTable`, your issue will be fixed.

```
class MyDataTable extends StatelessWidget
```